# How to make Chrome DevTools reload only selected resource?

Tags: javascript, extjs, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to force reloading only specific resource-files from DevTools?

I'm developing site with ExtJS MVC, that results to almost 100 JS files. Mostly I'm debugging the controller by filling an form -> sending form -> detecting an bug in controller -> fixing it -> reloading whole site -> filling the form again -> another bug -> reload...

It would be very helpful to reload only the controller-part of the code, so that the JS-files contructing the forms would not be affected, thus increasing load times and dropping need to fill the form on every iteration.

So, is it possible? Or could the browser even work this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use Local Modifications in Source panel (right click in panel) to change or debug Your code, or You can open specific js file in new windwow and than reload it, but I don`t think You can apply reloaded file to site without reloading it itself.

Comment: I had the same problem as in this question, but your suggestion is not very practical, because after the changes on Chrome Dev Tools, you must track all of them, and the recode them on original JavaScript (or as in my case, CoffeeScript)